# Holoviews: Code does not have UI components defined explicitly

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying the following sample code in Holoviews for creating a select dropdown and updating figure based on the selection.

```
macro_df = pd.read_csv('http://assets.holoviews.org/macro.csv', '\t')
key_dimensions   = [('year', 'Year'), ('country', 'Country')]
value_dimensions = [('unem', 'Unemployment'), ('capmob', 'Capital Mobility'),
                    ('gdp', 'GDP Growth'), ('trade', 'Trade')]
macro = hv.Table(macro_df, key_dimensions, value_dimensions)

%%opts Curve (color='k') Scatter [color_index=2 size_index=2 scaling_factor=1.4] (cmap='Blues' edgecolors='k')
gdp_curves = macro.to.curve('Year', 'GDP Growth')
gdp_curves
```

The figure is as below. Above code does not have an explicit definition of UI components or their control. How and where do we declare the 'Country' to be a select dropdown? How do we configure options so that 'Year' can be made a dropdown etc?

[image]

Comment: You can define with using the `GraphWidget` as done here - https://plot.ly/python/dropdown-widget/

Comment: @Vaulstein In the current code posted, I'm trying to understand where have they defined the select drop-down as a component

Comment: You are running it on a Notebook, right?

Comment: Yeah. Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example above the 'Country' dropdown is implicit generated. This is because the hv.Table has two so called key dimensions 'Year' and 'Country' (which you should think of as independent variables). When you run `macro.to.curve('Year', 'GDP Growth')` it therefore knows that there is a second independent variable (the 'Country') that it should group over. We can expand the `.to` declaration in the following way: `macro.to(hv.Curve, 'Year', 'GDP Growth', groupby='Country')`, which basically says "turn my macro table into a set of `hv.Curve` elements plotting 'GDP Growth' by 'Year' for each 'Country'.